# Wie zitiert ihr Markennamen in Büchern/Artikeln?

Tags: usage

Wie zitiert ihr Markennamen in Büchern/Artikeln?

Ich schreibe derzeit an einer Arbeit und frage mich, wie ich bspw. Windows, MATLAB, Maple oder Excel verwende.

Folgendes Beispiel demonstriert mein Problem mittels LaTeX-Beispiel:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Windows oder
 \item Windows\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} oder
 \item Windows\textsuperscript{\textcopyright} oder
 \item Windows\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also © (copyright) ist sicher nicht richtig, das ist das falsche Rechtsmittel. ™ oder ® passen eher. Grundsätzlich ist die Kennzeichnung von verwendeten Markennamen mit diesen Zeichen zumindest in Deutschland bzw. Österreich *nicht* verpflichtend.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Danke. Du könntest dein Kommentar auch als Antwort präsentieren, so dass ich ein Haken setzen kann ;-)

Comment: Hab ich getan. Wollte ursprünglich nur darauf hinweisen dass © nicht passt, ist dann doch mehr geworden ;-)

Comment: Windows für sich allein ist ein schlechtes Beispiel. Microsoft hat das zwar registriert bekommen (im zweiten Anlauf), aber es ist zweifelhaft, ob das überhaupt gültig ist. An sich ist nämlich Windows ein generischer Begriff für Fenstersysteme (z.B. X-Windows).

Comment: @starblue: Danke für die Erklärung. Ich werde wohl in diesem Fall Microsoft Windows nutzen. Dass sollte eindeutig sein.

Comment: BTW, du brauchst kein `\textsuperscript` bei `\texttrademark`. Das Zeichen ist idR schon hochgestellt: Windows™

Comment: *»schreibe derzeit an einer Arbeit«* An was für einer Arbeit? Wenn es eine Bachelor-Arbeit ist, liest die im Normalfall sowieso nur dein(e) Betreuer(in), also frag sie/ihn. Dasselbe gilt für Seminararbeiten. Master- und Diplomarbeiten haben in der Regel auch nicht mehr Leser, daher gilt hier derselbe Rat. Doktorarbeiten sind heutzutage meist Zusammenfassungen von Publikationen in wissenschaftlichen Magazinen, und dabei gelten die redaktionellen Vorgaben der Magazine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Das Zeichen [© (copyright)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urheberrecht) ist hier nicht korrekt, das ist das falsche Rechtsmittel. ™ oder ® passen hier eher.

- ™ wird verwendet um [*nicht* eingetragene Markennamen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unregistered_Trade_Mark) zu kennzeichnen.
- ® wird verwendet um [*eingetragene* Markennamen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_Trade_Mark) zu kennzeichnen.

Die Kennzeichnung von verwendeten Markennamen mit diesen Zeichen ist in Deutschland und Österreich jedoch [*nicht verpflichtend*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marke_%28Recht%29#Eintragungsverfahren_.28Deutschland.29):

> Ist eine Marke im Markenregister eingetragen, darf sie vom Markeninhaber mit dem Symbol ® (von englisch “registered trade mark“ = eingetragene Waren- oder Dienstleistungsmarke) neben der Marke gekennzeichnet werden. Es besteht aber keine Pflicht zu dieser Kennzeichnung.

Comment: Hm. Was ist mit dem oft zu lesenden Hinweis, dass alle genannten Marken ihren entsprechenden Inhabern gehören (irgendwo im "Vorspann" des Buches). Ersetzt es irgendwelche Kennzeichnungen im laufenden Text? Oder ist es einfach nur ein Artefakt, indem das Buch aus dem englischen übersetzt wurde und dort der Hinweis auch drinsteckt?

Comment: @0x6d64: das weiß ich leider nicht. Bin nicht in Marken-Recht ausgebildet, sondern nur ein teil-interessierter Laie. Die genauen Details sind mir also nicht geläufig. Allerdings halte ich die Möglichkeit für wahrscheinlich, dass es ein Übersetzungs-Artefakt ist.

Comment: Der Hinweis im Vorspann ist ein Versuch den Inhabern der Markenrechte den Vorwurf der "mißbräuchlichen Verwendung" ihres Markennamens zu erschweren. Er ersetzt m.W. nicht die Kennzeichnung im Buch. Tipp: in TeX lohnt es sich bei mehrfacher Verwendung eines Markennames die notwendige Auszeichnung über ein Makro zu definieren, falls irgendwann ein Rechteinhaber daherkommt, und den Markennamen unbedingt in Font xy gesetzt haben will. Beispiel: `\newcommand{\scm}{{Sun\texttrademark{} Cluster Manager\index{Sun Cluster Manager
}}\/}`

Comment: Da steht "darf sie vom Markeninhaber ... mit dem Symbol ... gekennzeichnet werden". Dass andere sie damit auch kennzeichnen dürfen entnehme ich dem Satz nicht, wie auch nicht den Anspruch des Fragestellers Markeninhaber zu sein.

Comment: @0x6d64: Dass eine genannte Marke einem entsprechenden Inhaber gehört ist m.E. tautologisch. Nicht genannte Marken gehören wohl auch ihren Inhabern - das dürfte einfach die Definition von Markeninhaber bzw. gehören sein.

Answer (score 3):

Viele große Markeninhaber haben Richtlinien aufgestellt, wie man ihre Markennamen verwenden muss. Es ist zwar fraglich, wie weit man sich daran halten muss, gerade hierzulande, andererseits kann es nicht schaden, [davon](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/Trademarks/Usage/General.aspx) mal etwas [gehört](http://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html) zu haben.

Wenn du eine Arbeit zum Beispiel für eine Hochschule schreibst, kannst du dort auch Informationen über die Verwendung von Marken bekommen - mitunter gibt es entsprechende Vorgaben, die du ohnehin einhalten musst.

In der Regel muss man da nicht so kleinlich sein und ein genereller Disclaimer über verwendete Marken reicht völlig aus. Außerdem kann es sinnvoll sein, in den Begriffs- oder Abkürzungslisten einfach den kompletten Markennamen mit allem Trara und eine Kurzform aufzulisten. Wenn man nämlich im Text andauernd [Microsoft® WinFX™ Software Development Kit for Microsoft® Pre-Release Windows Operating System Code-Named "Longhorn", Beta 1 Web Setup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jonathanh/whats-the-longest-microsoft-product-name) lesen muss, wird es irgendwann ziemlich anstrengend ;)

Selbst die "normalen" Namen wie "Microsoft Windows Vista" können, ständig im Fließtext wiederholt, äußerst anstrengend zu lesen sein. Die Lesbarkeit sollte hier sicher Vorrang haben. Sofern man den Namen entweder bereits definiert hat oder bei der ersten Verwendung mit den entsprechenden Symbolen versehen hat, sollte das auch kein Problem darstellen.

Unabhängig von Markennamen kann es sinnvoll sein, Eigennamen (einschließlich Produkt- und Markennamen) gesondert hervorzuheben. Kapitälchen oder kursive Schrift wären da einige Möglichkeiten.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung -- Die Uni ist schon lang vorbei (leider). Ich überlege ein kleines Tutorium zu schreiben, wobei dieses im Netz veröffentlicht werden soll. Ich habe also absolut keine Vorgaben.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Ich kam auf das Beispiel mit der Hochschule, weil bei uns in der Firma kürzlich bei einer Bachelorarbeit, in der zwei bekannte Handy-Betriebssysteme vorkommen, genau diese Frage aufkam und die Hochschule leider *keine* Vorgaben gemacht hatte :) Wenn du einen komplett öffentlichen Artikel schreiben willst, kann es wirklich nicht schaden, die Richtlinien der Markeninhaber einmal gesehen zu haben, um grobe Schnitzer zu vermeiden. Ansonsten reicht natürlich Joachim Sauers Hinweis, dass die entsprechende Kennzeichnung hierzulande nicht verpflichtend ist, zumal als Privatmann.

Comment: Du unterstellst einerseits, dass es fraglich ist, ob man sich dran halten muss, aber sagst andererseits, dass man sich das, was sie selbst einseitig erklärt haben, besser durchgelesen haben soll. Besser - wofür? Gerade weil es, wie Du m.E. zurecht schreibst, nervend ist, ständig vom Kult um die Marken belästigt zu werden, ist es erholsam überhauptnichts dazu beizutragen; das Lesen größenwahnsinniger Ansprüche kann aber zur Einschüchterung führen. Außerdem ist es eine kollossale Zeitverschwendung. Es schadet durchaus. Am Ende schreibt man noch "Kaisers Supermarkt" mit Apostroph.